# How do I call a C++ function from C?

Tags: c, linker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a lib written in C++ from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014851/how-to-call-a-lib-written-in-c-from-c)

I am tinkering with [pHash](http://www.phash.org/docs/howto.html) and I want to call the function for generating a perceptual hash from file location. When I try to call the function called ph_dct_imagehash the compiler throws this error:

```
/usr/include/CImg.h:72:18: fatal error: cstdio: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

At this point I realize that pHash is written in C++, so including C++ headers in a C program isn't going to work. Nonetheless the function itself seems like it should be callable from C as none of it's parameters nor it's return value use C++ constructs. Is there any good way to call the C++ function ph_dct_imagehash from C?

Note: I am mostly doing this to get better at C (not C++). This is why I am restricting myself to C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have an unmangled symbol name to call, you can link your C++ library with your C program pretty easily.  You'll want to make a C-safe header file or other way to forward declare the function name, and then just link things together at the end (make sure to use a C++-aware linker!).

Here's a simple example:

```
$ cat cplusplus.cpp 
#include <string>

extern "C"
const char *cplusplusFunction(void)
{
    static std::string a = "Hello, C++";
    return a.c_str();
}
$ cat example.c 
#include <stdio.h>

const char *cplusplusFunction(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", cplusplusFunction());
    return 0;
}
$ c++ -c -o cplusplus.o cplusplus.cpp
$ cc -c -o example.o example.c 
$c++ -o example example.o cplusplus.o
$ ./example 
Hello, C++
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to separate your C++ code functions from the C code.

Typically, that's done by having a .h file that contains only C (not C++) declarations of functions and C data structures needed to solve the problem, and a C++ file that contains the C to C++ interface functions.

You will also need to use

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
.... your types and functions ... 
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

in your header file, to ensure that the C++ compiler doesn't "mangle" the names (marking the type of parameters in the name of the function, e.g. the function Blur(int x, int y) may be called _Blur_ii, where regular C doesn't add this sort of "extra stuff" on the function name, so the C compiler will make a call to _Blur - and of course, the linker says "Can't find _Blur" when you try to link.

Edit: Additionally, make absolute 100% sure that you don't have exceptions "leaking" into the C code. If you do, anything could happen, and it's usually not gold falling from the sky, but rather some bad stuff... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a C++ compiler (say g++ instead of gcc), you can call C++ code from your C code seamlessly and everything will work just fine.
This will be the case since unless you're doing something really strange, C is contained within C++..

And if it still does not work when you compile with g++, you should change file suffix from .c to .cc, .cpp, .cxx, etc. Preferably .cc

Comment: Except if the code you are trying to compile uses C++ reserved words, such as new, class, typename, etc. And if you have many thousand lines of code, that you only want to hook a small part of into some C++, that could very well be a problem.

Comment: +1 @MatsPetersson.  My personal pet peeve is all of the casting around `malloc`.  "Fixing" all of those can be a chore.